# How to use SWRevealViewController with iPad SplitViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, swrevealviewcontroller

Hi I am using `storyboard` for my iPad app. How can I add `SWRevealViewController` to my app. I want to add slide view to my master view controller. Can any body please suggest me. I am loading my splitView using the following code in `AppDelegate.h`

```
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CouponDetailRoot"];
```

[image]

Comment: have u reviewed http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  I am doing a universal app. I worked out my iPhone using the above tutorial. I am trying to add same functionality to iPad also.

Comment: k what the problem u meet

Comment: I added my storyboard image now.please check it once. I am not getting where I need to add the SWRevealViewController.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, does the SWRevealViewController have to be the root view controller? That would mean it's in direct competition with the splitViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the Master View Controller the sw_front view of the SWRevealViewController. Then, if you want the detail view to be collapsed so only the master view shows up at first, create a class like this and assign it to the Master View Controller in storyboard:

```
    import UIKit

class GlobalSplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self
    }

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```